# how to get last index after reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple tabs. When i clicks on tab it got active class and content gets change. But problem is developer is calling the content through a server side code in which page gets refresh and on every call url gets change.

In this scenario after every refresh active class removes from the current tab.

I got to know there is a way that i define text on data attribute and call that attribute text on url hidden field and than compare it. so i can define the active class if comparison will be true.

But i don't know how to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">link 1</li>
      <li>link 2</li>
      <li>link 3</li>
      <li>link 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="one">
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <p>Paragraph 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

js:

```
$(".content .one").not(":first").hide();
$(document).on("click", ".menu li", function(){
  var i = $(this).index();
  $(".menu li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active")
  $(".content .one").hide();
  $(".content .one:eq( "+ i +")").show();

})
```

sample:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azMdJK

Let me know if there is any other work around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LocalStorage` of HTML5 for saving last Index, then you can get value of last index after reload also.

```
localStorage.setItem("lastindex", 'value');
```

I have created sample code for you:

```
lastIndex = localStorage.getItem('lastindex');
if(lastIndex == null){
    $(".content .one").not(":first").hide();
}
else{ 
    lastIndex = parseInt(lastIndex)+1;
    $(".content").children().not(".one:nth-child("+lastIndex+")").hide();
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul li:nth-child('+lastIndex+')').addClass('active');
}
$(document).on("click", ".menu li", function(){
  var i = $(this).index();
  localStorage.setItem("lastindex", i);
  // add/remove active class
  $(".menu li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active")
  // hide/show content
  $(".content .one").hide();
  $(".content .one:eq( "+ i +")").show();

})
```

See [**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x5totc0f/7/), which maintain last tab after reloading page also.

Comment: Thanks @Manwal. But in your demo tabs are not working.

Comment: strange i checked in mozilla and chrome. nothing happens when i am clicking on tabs.

Comment: Ohhhh God finally. Great. You can accept answer if solves you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of history API and query string. Set url as `?tab=tabIndex` and process the query string on page loading.

eg: On second tab click, set url as http://www.example.com?tab=2. If I'm trying to load http://www.example.com?tab=3 get current tab as 3 and activate the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by following ways,

- You can append tab id in url as fragment identifier ([hashtag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)), and then when page loads you can apply jQuery and trigger click on particular tab.
- You can save data in cookie, as soon as tab is clicked save it's ID in cookie, and on page load check for that ID and then above same process. (trigger click on that particular tab).
- Better way, process server side calls with AJAX.

Manwal's solution can be used also, HTML5 Storage.